# Is there a term for vertically low typefaces?

Tags: fonts, style, style-identification

I am looking for a choice of fonts where (in capitals) the horizontal lines are relatively low. For example in this Martini logo:

[image]

The horizontal in the A and R are way below the middle of the shape. Perhaps there is a term for this like "ground-bound" fonts or something.

Otherwise, perhaps somebody knows a list of fonts with this characteristic. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of 'art deco' and 'arts and crafts' era typefaces will have atypically low (or high) cross bars. Use those search terms on a site like MyFonts to find a variety of options.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a typeface with low crossbars.
While that might be a difficult term to search from, you might start out by looking through those that have a small [x-height](http://www.fontscape.com/explore?F4L). These will occasionally have low crossbars as well, to match with the height of the lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

I think I once heard someone refer to characters with that characteristic as "top heavy", so you could try looking for that

Answer (score 1):

Neutraface – from 2002, but inspired by the modernist typefaces used by architect Richard Neutra for building signage during the first half of the 20th century (Futura came from that era too.)

http://www.houseind.com/fonts/neutraface/fontspecimens

Answer (score 0):

I would simply describe them as having low **crossbars**.